# Retrogaming Troubles

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

```
After making a few tweaks, I got some retro video games to work on my PC.
However, now these games are taking up too much space!
What should I do?

Dictator Amin / Raw rock / NATO member
②__ ___ ⑧__
Stole / Basil, e.g.
_①__ ④___
1492 ship / Electrical unit / Anatomical pouch
⑩___ _⑬__ ___
Understand, slangily / Tibetan ox / Silent approval 
_⑪__ _③_ ___
General Grant's first name / Hwy.
⑥____ __
Made in Abyss robot / Game on a green
___ __⑦_
Title / Jewel
___⑭ ___
Kevin who played Hercules / Persia, now / Taken-back cars
_____ ___⑨ ___⑮_
Fashion designer Christian / Sewn edge / Picture puzzle
____ ⑫__ __⑤__
```

Comment: Please can you format this, not as a codeblock, but using tables and paragraphs — or at a note as to why that's not possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After solving for the clues, the key is that

> the numbered letters in each line can be substituted to form a retro video game when read backwards.

Dictator Amin / Raw rock / NATO member

> IDI ORE USA => AS(T)EROID(S)

Stole / Basil, e.g.

> TOOK HERB => BRE(A)KO(U)T

1492 ship / Electrical unit / Anatomical pouch

> NINA VOLT SAC => CASTL(E)VANI(A)

Understand, slangily / Tibetan ox / Silent approval

> GROK YAK NOD => DONK(E)Y KO(N)G

General Grant's first name / Hwy.

> HIRAM RD => DR MARI(O)

Made in Abyss robot / Game on a green

> REG GOLF => F(R)OGGER

Title / Jewel

> NAME GEM => MEG(A)MAN

Kevin who played Hercules / Persia, now / Taken-back cars

> SORBO IRAN REPOS => S(U)PER (M)ARIO BROS

Fashion designer Christian / Sewn edge / Picture puzzle

> DIOR HEM REBUS => SU(P)ER ME(T)ROID

Finally,

> ordering the substituted letters reveals that you should **USE A PORTMANTEAU**.

Comment: I don't know if this is what OP @IAmLucidNonsense intended, but just in case, I'll add that rot13("ergeb" pna nyfb zrna "onpxjneq").